# How can I learn a large amount of java concepts in a short amount of time?

Tags: java, string, loops, methods, character

So I recently learned about a scholarship that my school has set up with CISCO and in order for me to even be acknowledged for the scholarship I have to learn the following JAVA concepts:

- Mathematical Functions
- Characters
- Strings
- Loops
- Methods

I'm still learning Java so this is sort of intimidating given the timeline that I have from today until next Wednesday (3-29-17.)

Could someone give me insight to how you break down the learning of new material in a short amount of time?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WPvGqX-TXP0

Comment: read up some examples and practice. You can learn the basic of these in a few days. characters are just a letter or digit (or special ones). A String is how you work with multiple characters e.g. `"hello"` is a string. Math functions are the same as you learnt in high school. Only loops and methods you might need to learn much.

Comment: you can start with 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html and after this you can go in detail on each of the topic using this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you should check the official documentation and the tutorials provided there - as *@ChrisK* suggested (for completness, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) is the link again).

Additionally, you could check those links:

- [Mathematical Functions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/java_lang_math.htm)
- [Methods](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm)
- [Strings](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_strings.htm)
- [Character](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_characters.htm)
- [Loops](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You can search in google about what you want to learn also in youtube too,
but you can check the official tutorials from Oracle
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

YouTube is a great way to learn a lot in a little bit of time. I was able to learn in a month or so the same amount they covered in my first year of college so without having to learn OOP concepts, a week and a half should be a decent amount of time. Also stackoverflow has great resources and a helpful community (clearly as you're posting here). Also as mentioned by Chris, Java is very well documented so anything you want to learn is online.

Good luck!